# html/css - centered, horizontal list of imgs with text under each img

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/kGd8c/

```
a.button{
    float:left;
    width:80px;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666;
}
a.button:hover{
    color:#000;
    border-bottom:3px double #000;
}
```

EXCEPT - I need the list to be horizontally centered.
Any ideas?

Comment: Like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/kGd8c/20/)?

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/kGd8c/22/

I added a container div around your code.

HTML

```
<div class="container">

<!-- your code -->

</div>
```

CSS

and then changed , added to the css

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
    background: grey;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

a.button {
    width:80px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#666;
    display: inline-block;

}

a.button:hover {
    color:#000;
    border-bottom:3px double #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a.button to `display: inline-block;`, rather than `float: left;` and wrap the anchors in a containing element that has `text-align: center;`

Check out [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGd8c/19/)